# How to integrate create-react-app and static content?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a little React based tool, and would like to add a few static html pages to it, using the same design. The way it is now is that I have the common parts (header, footer) in `index.html`, and the common styling in `index.css`. All the logic and styling of my tool are in React components. The project is based on create-react-app. I am not using react-router, but I am thinking about doing so.

- The simplest solution is to just copy `index.html`, and use that as a template for my static pages, but then I would have to keep them in sync which is tedious.
- I could also create my static pages as react components. If I just have one or two, that seems like a good option. This would integrate with react-router. However, then the static pages would also be js-only.
- Another option is to create my static site with a static site generator like hexo, and have that *generate* the `index.html` used by c-r-a. This seems the way to go if I want to add something like a blog. Also everything except the tool remains js-free. The downside is that it adds another build step.

Is there any recommended / best / elegant way to add simple static HTML (or, say, markdown) pages to a react app?

Comment: I think the simplest way would be using react-router but this seems like a personal opinion and also really depends on what your app needs.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js is worth a look. It moves the react routing to the folder structure, with a static folder for HTML pages.